# What is the difference between these comparisons using || and ,

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these two statements. I get different results when I use these interchangeably. I was hoping that someone could explain this for me. So whats the difference between, this...

```
else if ( ( elecshow ==2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,16 ) )
```

and this...

```
else if ( ( elecshow ==2 ) || ( elecshow ==3 ) || ( elecshow ==4 ) || ( elecshow ==5 ) || ( elecshow ==6 ) || ( elecshow ==8 ) || ( elecshow ==9 ) || ( elecshow ==10 ) || ( elecshow ==16 ) )
```

I know this is simple stuff but your input would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the jQuery?

Comment: That else if !== that other else if

Comment: Yea that was a typo, sorry. it should have been == not !=

Comment: I guess what I am wondering is why do I get different results when I separate the statement with () || (). The || just means "or" right? so why doesn't == 2,3,4 work the same way?

Comment: It doesn't work the same way because it's an entirely different operator with different semantics. Is there a reason you expect them to  be the same?

Comment: Simply because comparison doesn't work like that. You can learn more about comparison by reading the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_when_to_use_them

Comment: The only reason is that I don't understand. but now I do, Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Check what the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) actually does. Your first snippet is equivalent to

```
else if ( ((((((((elecshow ==2),3),4),5),6),8),9),10),16 )
```

or (if we assume that evaluating `elecshow` doesn't throw etc.) just

```
else if ( 16 )
```

You will need to use the second one, although you might be able to shorten it to something like

```
else if (elecshow > 1 && elecshow <= 10 && elecshow != 7 || elecshow == 16)
```

Comment: For completeness, should probably add a test to make sure it's an integer.

Comment: @squint: Yeah, maybe, but that depends on what the test actually needs to do.

Comment: I was using this with two groups of radio buttons that had numerical values attached to them, I then wrote a variable... var secondmtl = $j('input[name=second]:checked', '#second-metal').val()*1;

I used the above to collect the numbers and a third to add them together, if the numbers == # || == 4 etc it would change some classes. I know this was simple but I am just now diving into the logic of coding.

Thank you for your answers This has been a big help.

Answer (score 2):

The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand

Combined with the fact that `==` has [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `,` what happens here is that `elecshow ==2` is evaluated, then `3`, then `4`, ... and finally `16`.

The last evaluation is returned and, `16` being a truthy value, the execution will enter the `else if`.

The result differs from

```
else if ( ( elecshow ==2 ) || ( elecshow ==3 ) || ( elecshow ==4 ) || ( elecshow ==5 ) || ( elecshow ==6 ) || ( elecshow ==8 ) || ( elecshow ==9 ) || ( elecshow ==10 ) || ( elecshow ==16 ) )
```

simply because it's an entirely different operator!